# dojo claro and sizing

Tags: css, dojo

I'm not sure if this is some css issue I've never run into before, or it's an issue with using the new claro theme in dojo 1.5. But right now, what CSS says is 100% sizing doesn't include the borders of my BorderContainer:

css:

```
html,body, .dijitBorderContainer {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;    
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0em;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 300px;
}
```

and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>stuff</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.0/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
        @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
        @import "css/application.css";
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var djConfig = {
            isDebug: false,
            parseOnLoad: true,
            baseUrl: './',
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require('dijit.layout.BorderContainer');
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" liveSplitters="true"></div>
</body>
```

And with this setup, the bordercontainer is just slightly too large for the window and brings up the scroll bars. All that doesn't fit is the border. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Dojo but what you are experiencing sounds like standard CSS behaviour. CSS width refers to the width of the element's content only, excluding margin, padding and border. Have a look at this page on the [CSS box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

Comment: Thanks, steered me in right direction. I had to add "border: 0px solid white;" to the dijitBorderContainer. "border:0px;" doesn't do it. Has to be  "border: 0px solid white;". I have no idea why that works.

Comment: Just a guess, but `border-style: none` might work as well, because it's the style that determines whether the border is displayed or not.